# Replacing weapons in Ork mob

Tags: warhammer-40k, orks, space-orks

Ork codex says that Ork Boyz has the following option:

> For every ten Orks in the mob, one Ork may exchange his slugga or shoota for:
>
> - big shoota (+5 points per model)
> - rokkit launcha (+10 points per model)

Lets say I have a 30-Ork mob. Does that mean that I can have 3 big shootas AND 3 rokkit launchas in it or I can only have 3 of either big shoota or rokkit launcha?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are allowed 1 heavy weapon per 10 Orks, but you can choose which one it is - a Big Shoota (BS) or Rokkit Launcha (RL). They don't all have to be the same type. In other words, with 30 Orks, the maximum heavy weapons you are allowed to have are either:

```
3RL
1BS + 2RL
2BS + 1RL
3BS
```